# Not a Single Group Function in paid date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a oracle 11g sql code to show weekly report, but getting error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function .
and the error cursor pointed to first line the PAID_DATE => TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'YEAR') "YEAR",

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'YEAR') "YEAR", 
    TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'MONTH') "MONTH",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'D') >= '1' AND TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'DD') <=7 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) "MINGGU1",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'D') >= '8' AND TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'DD') <=15 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) "MINGGU2",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'D') >= '16' AND TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'DD') <=23 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) "MINGGU3",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'D') >= '24' THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) "MINGGU4"
FROM 
    PAID_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `GROUP BY` clause to specify the columns you are grouping by:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'YEAR') "YEAR", 
    TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'MONTH') "MONTH",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'D') >= '1' AND TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'DD') <=7 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) "MINGGU1",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'D') >= '8' AND TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'DD') <=15 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) "MINGGU2",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'D') >= '16' AND TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'DD') <=23 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) "MINGGU3",
    SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'D') >= '24' THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) "MINGGU4"
FROM 
    PAID_TABLE
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'YEAR'), TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'MONTH') -- added line
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `GROUP BY`.  However, I wouldn't recommend doing string comparisons for day of the month.

Instead:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'YEAR MONTH') as YEAR_MONTH, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM PAIDDATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) as MINGGU1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM PAIDDATE) BETWEEN 8 AND 15 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) as MINGGU2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM PAIDDATE) BETWEEN 16 AND 23 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) as MINGGU3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM PAIDDATE) >= 24 THEN TOTAL_PAID ELSE 0 END) as MINGGU4
FROM PAID_TABLE
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(PAID_DATE, 'YEAR MONTH')
ORDER BY MIN(PAID_DATE);
```

Note that this also combines the first two columns into a single column.  If you are going to write out the date as strings, one column makes sense to me (although I prefer the `'YYYY-MM'` format).

I added an `ORDER BY` so the rows are returned chronologically.